# tuple of a nested list

Tags: python, tuples, binary-tree

consider having a nested list that contains nested lists like following:

```
list = [[], 3, [[2], [4], [5], [[],[3,[5,8]]]]]
```

how could I get the tuple of this list that contains just tuples?!!!
the reason for this question is that I want to use it for representing a binary tree that I am building with some values(unbalanced) and the out put must be in tuple. the tree is being built in steps and because the tuple is immutable I can not use it from beginning. 
the out put must have a form like this in the end:

with values:3 5 4 2 8 (starting with 3 as root):

```
((-,2,-),3,((-,4,-),5,(-,8,-)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the tuple of this list that contains just tuples"?

Comment: I want to have all the lists(all the nested ones) as tuple

Comment: well, your question is not well formatted and most probably you will get downvoted. please learn markdown. then include a visual representation of what you mean by binary tree. IMO worry about the tuple thing the last. learn about recursion, list comprehension and mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the list and recursively convert a list item to a tuple if the item is an instance of a list:

```
def to_tuple(lst):
    return tuple(to_tuple(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in lst)
```

so that given a list converted to a binary tree in the format suggested by your question:

```
def btree(lst):
    tree = []
    for item in lst:
        node = tree
        while node:
            left, value, right = node
            node = right if value < item else left
        node[:] = [], item, []
    return tree

lst = [3, 5, 4, 2, 8]
```

where `btree(lst)` returns:

```
[[[], 2, []], 3, [[[], 4, []], 5, [[], 8, []]]]
```

`to_tuple(btree(lst))` would return:

```
(((), 2, ()), 3, (((), 4, ()), 5, ((), 8, ())))
```

If you prefer to have `'-'` in place of empty tuples, you can make `to_tuple` return `'-'` instead when the generated tuple is empty:

```
def to_tuple(lst):
    return tuple(to_tuple(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in lst) or '-'
```

so that `to_tuple(btree(lst))` returns:

```
(('-', 2, '-'), 3, (('-', 4, '-'), 5, ('-', 8, '-')))
```